# Relational mapping in hibernate, one to one or many to one?

Tags: hibernate, mapping, relationship

I have this situation: one person can have many bank accounts, yet one bank account can belong only to one specific person. Obvious one to many relationship:
[image]

My model for BankAccount class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bank_account")
public class Bank {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="bank_id")
    private int bankId;

    @Column(name="account_number")
    private String accNumber;

    @ManyToOne // or @OneToOne?
    private Person person;
```

Problem is when I look at my diagram, I can clearly see `OneToMany` relationship, so reversed it will mean many to one. But from the side of ***"one bank account can belong only to one specific person"*** makes me think that there might be `OneToOne` relationship needed. Which one is right? When considering logic for mapping relationships in model should I take just reversed relationship from diagram or look at relationship of one child object towards parent table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right in some manner a OnetoOne relation is a ManyTOne except the fact that it includes a unicity constraint.

In your case you said: **"one bank account can belong only to one specific person"** but if you put a OneToOne relation it implies that in your bank account table the foreign key for a specific person must be appear only once.

This is why the reversed mapping of a OneToMany is a ManytoOne which allow multiple FK otherwise it don't make sense.

Just a little tips:

Try to remember that a oneToOne relation probably means that it is possible your 2 tables be just one because the objects involved in the relation are higly coupled and dependant.

Hope it's clear

Comment: Thanks! That was very clear, informative answer. I was looking at model as if it was one object, I didn't realize I should be looking at it like a whole table)